# How can i use javascript with actionscript?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

I'am having a flex web project and i need to use some java script functions (e.g,geolocation) so can anyone help me to understand the way of relating them to each others.

Answer (score 0):

The ExternalInterface class is used for communication between swf's and the javascripts located on the same page.

By using the ExternalInterface.call("functionName", functionParams...) function in as3 you can call any function in javascript within your webpage.
To register functions to be called in flex from javascript use ExternalInterface.addCallback("functionName",  functionReference).

Usage:

```
package {
   import flash.display.MovieClip;
   import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

   public class EITest extends MovieClip {
     public function EITest() {
         registerWithJavascript();
         makeCall();
     }

     public function registerWithJavascript():void {
       // To register a function with javascript
       var isAvailable:Boolean = ExternalInterface.available;

       if(isAvailable)
          ExternalInterface.addCallback("callbackName", actualCallback);
     }

     public function actualCallback():void {
         // Do something
     }

     public function makeCall():void {
       // To call a javascript function
       var isAvailable:Boolean = ExternalInterface.available;
       var someParamToSend:int = 13;

       if(isAvailable)
          ExternalInterface.call("someFunction", someParamToSend);
     }
   }
 }
```